# WebDB - For each Column, in Each Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, web-sql

in webDB, EG: HTML5 SQLLite

How can I do the following:

```
For i = 0 To RS.Fields.Count -1
    Response.Write "Field Name: " & RS.Fields(i).Name & "<br>"
    Response.Write "Field Value: " & RS(i) & "<br>"
Next
```

If, at all...

Or, another question would be, how can I iterate the columns themselves and optimally, retrieve the columns name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
function showQueryResults(tx, r) {
    // alert("showing [" + r.rows.length.toString() + "] query results");
    var rs = null;
    var $tr, $td;

    var $t = $("<table border='1' cellpadding='2 cellspacing='0' />");

    if (r.rows.length > 0) {
        rs = r.rows.item(0);
        $tr = $("<tr />");
        $.each(rs, function (key, val) {
            $tr.append($("<th>" + key + "</th>"));
        });
        $t.append($tr);

        for (var i = 0; i < r.rows.length; i++) {
            rs = r.rows.item(i);
            $tr = $("<tr />");
            $.each(rs, function (key, val) {
                $tr.append($("<td>" + rs[key] + "</td>"));
            });
            $t.append($tr);
            $tr = null;
        };
    };

    $("#formHolder").children().remove();
    $("#formHolder").append($t).show();
    $t = null;

};
```